# How do I Manage aspect ratio on entering XR mode in three.js?

Tags: three.js, webxr

I have a responsive page and a canvas in this page that resizes as the page size changes. All this works well. The aspect ratio of my 3D scene is maintained as the canvas is resized. Let's say that my canvas is currently 1000 x 500 then sure enough my camera has an aspect ratio of 2.

When I enter XR mode though things change. The canvas now occupies the whole device width and height, which makes sense. However the original aspect ratio seems to be maintained so that the original 3D scene, when rendered in VR, gets stretched or squashed.

Here's a really simple [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andymgar/kayz86rh/37/) that will show you the issue. The screen height is divided into two equal parts and the scene, comprising just one sphere, is rendered in the lower half. Proportions are correct. Press the "Enter VR" button and you'll see straight away that the sphere is no longer spherical. It's so simple and basic I clearly must be doing something fundamentally wrong.

```
// renderer
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
root = document.getElementById("scene");
renderer.setSize( root.clientWidth, root.clientHeight );
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.xr.enabled = true;

root.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

button = document.getElementById("button");
button.appendChild( VRButton.createButton( renderer ) );  
// scene
scene = new THREE.Scene();

// camera  
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, root.clientWidth / root.clientHeight, 1, 10000 );
camera.position.set( 4, 1.6, 10 );

// controls
controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

// light
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 2 );
light.position.set( 2, 20, 20 );
scene.add( light );

// geometry
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 2, 12, 12 );

// material
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
color: 0x00ffff, 
flatShading: true
} );

// mesh
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
mesh.position.set(0, 1.6, -5)
scene.add( mesh );|
```

How, on entering VR mode, can I make sure the renderer adopts the original aspect ratio?

Having browsed the docs I cannot see a way to do this. Also, every three.js example I have seen that uses VR takes up the whole device screen before entering VR so there's no insights I can get from these examples.

I understand that in XR mode there is both an original camera and an XR camera. I can access the two xr cameras (right and left) using webXRManager.getCamera() method but they both seem to have aspectRatio = 1, whereas my original PerspectiveCamera has an aspect ratio of 2. I tried changing the aspect ratio of the main (non-xr) camera but that seems to have no effect once in VR mode.

All in all I am a bit confused! Any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So after a little more digging the issue seems to be this:

Clicking the "Enter VR" button will create a new XR session but will not resize the renderer. However the renderer target (in this case my canvas) has now changed. Before clicking the button it is only half the screen height and after clicking the button it is the full screen height.

The XRButton has an onSessionStarted function that is triggered when an XR session request has been granted:

```
navigator.xr.requestSession( 'immersive-vr', sessionInit ).then( onSessionStarted );
```

The onSessionStarted function then proceeds to establish the XR session:

```
await renderer.xr.setSession( session );
```

Once this setSession call is made the renderer cannot be resized since the session "isPresenting" flag will be true and resize is then prevented.

The solution seems to be to call the renderer.resize function after the XR session request has been granted but before the session has been established. Adding a setSize call at this point fixes things:

```
async function onSessionStarted( session ) {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    session.addEventListener( 'end', onSessionEnded );
    await renderer.xr.setSession( session );
    button.textContent = 'EXIT VR';
    currentSession = session;
}
```

But this isn't a great solution because I don't want to change the library code. But I cannot see any other way to achieve the same thing. I'll post this on the three.js gitHub and see if I am missing something.